# GCC error : undefined reference

Tags: c, linker, beagleboard, math.h

I am trying to compile some C code on a beagleboard xm. I try to compile, but I get the error: undefined reference to 'isfinite' which is in the math.h library. This code compiles perfectly in all my other computers, and I do include -lm in my makefile.

I suspect that it may be my compiler, maybe it is an over version? On the beagleboard it's version 4.3.3, but on my computer it's 4.7.3, but I don't know how to get a later version. I thought opkg would automatically get the latest available.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: Does `-lm` appear after your object files?  If not, fix things so that it does.  If it appears before the object files, the linker will ignore the library (it doesn't provide any symbols that it needs when it scans the library), then it'll read the object files, and then it won't find the symbols in the main C library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `infinite()` is part of C99. Your compiler is by default using an older version of the C language. You need to compile with the the flag `-std=c99` to enable this macro.

> `gnu89' GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is
>   the default for C code.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

`isfinite` is part of the C++11 standard and gcc 4.3.3 is to old to know that. Try 
`int finite(double x);` or `int finitef(float x);`.

Comment: @tomato The question is about C, not C++.

Comment: It is part of C99 as a macro, in C++ it is a function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/isfinite/